# similar to Quartz Jboss annotation

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, quartz-scheduler

Someone told me that there are some annotations in JBoss Application Server that can do similar work as Quartz. What are these annotations? Are they better than Quartz?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post lists the options available within JBoss: http://anilsaldhana.blogspot.com/2011/05/scheduler-jobs-in-jboss-as.html

To summarize:

1. Quartz Scheduler:

   - http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Quartz_scheduler_integration.html
   - http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowtoconfigureaQuartzservice
2. java.util.Timer:

   - You will need to create your own instances of timer tasks in your application.
3. JBoss Scheduler:

   - http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Additional_Services-Scheduling_Tasks.html
   - Section 10.7 and 10.8 of http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/index.html

Comment: I can do Schedule on Jboss by @Schedule() annotation  and by Quartz too. is there any difference of them?

Comment: @Schedule is an EJB3.1 annotation that uses whatever scheduling service implementation is configured for the EJB container.

Comment: where can I see, which scheduling service implementation is configured for EJB container? and is @Schedule is an EJB3.1 en implementation of Quartz?... or is this the another one?